# Need help for code returning ambiguous error

Tags: postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and am trying to create a view and getting the following error:

> ERROR:  column reference "stn_master_id" is ambiguous

Code is:

```
CREATE  VIEW V_StationStaff AS
SELECT Station_name, station_id, first_name, last_name, stn_master_id
FROM STATION_EXTENSION S, MASTER M
WHERE S.stn_master_id = M.stn_master_id
ORDER BY Station_name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify which id you want:

```
CREATE  VIEW V_StationStaff AS
SELECT Station_name, station_id, first_name, last_name, S.stn_master_id
FROM STATION_EXTENSION S, MASTER M
WHERE S.stn_master_id = M.stn_master_id
ORDER BY Station_name ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Just specify which table's "stn_master_id" you want, by using the alias.  Since they are equal, it doesn't matter which one you pick.

If you had done the join like this:

```
FROM STATION_EXTENSION S JOIN MASTER M USING (stn_master_id)
```

then PostgreSQL would be able to figure out that it doesn't matter, and let you leave off the alias.